# How to remove 'English' words in tm_map?

Tags: r, dictionary, tm

`tm_map` is very uesful when one deal with text-mining stuff. Now I gonna remove "English" words in texts by `tm_map`. Anybody can teach me how to write the syntax (as `removeNumbers`)?

Comment: could you provide some more details like what did you try, and what is not working?

Comment: The syntax is `tm_map(corpus, removeWords, mylist)`, where the variable "mylist" is the list of words to remove.  Of course you will need to find/ create the list of "English" words.

Comment: >library(Matrix)  >library(tm)   >library(tmcn) >library(SnowballC)

>d.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(F31A$newc)) >d.corpus <- tm_map(d.corpus, removeNumbers) >tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(d.corpus, control = list(weighting=weightTfIdf, wordLengths = c(4,Inf))) >freq<-rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))   >tail(sort(freq), n=50)

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to user-define a list of words or more radically, to load a whole English dictionary as a list of words. In the first code to remove words the code would be:

```
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, c("will", "oxford",
                                    "chart", "spain",
                                    "economy", "expect", 
                                    "still", "rose", "fall"))
```